# Assigning to self in Python, after un-pickling an instance of the same class

Tags: python, pickle, self

It's easiest to illustrate what I'm trying to do with an example:

```
Class A(object):

    someVariable = 0

    def __init__(self):

        self.someVariable = 1

        with open('file.pkl','wb') as pfile:
            pickle.dump(self,pfile)

        self.someVariable = 2

        self = pickle.load('file.pkl')

        print self.someVariable == 1

blah = A()
```

And I would like this to print True, but I think that the self object is immutable in Python. It will be a pain to restructure my code, is there any way to quickly achieve the above?

Comment: self is just an ordinary variable afaik. You've discarded the original object that was passed in as the self parameter, and after that line self refers to a different object, whose "someVariable" attribute is 1.

Comment: This question has symptoms from the classic "X-Y" problem, where you are asking about how to do Y (the solution you devised) instead of asking about X (your real problem). What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: The problem that Raito answered below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pickle `self.__dict__` which stores every attribute of the class.
And all you have to do is to unpickle it. (As you've figured, it's a dict.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you really want, but I guess you are trying to persist an instance to disk. My take would be something like this:

```
class A(object):
    some_variable = 0

    def __init__(self, value=1):
        self.some_variable = value

    def save(self, name='file.pkl'):
        with open(name,'wb') as pfile:
            pickle.dump(self, pfile)

    @staticmethod
    def load(name='file.pkl'):
        return pickle.load(open(name, 'rb'))
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> a = A(2)
>>> a.some_variable
2

>>> a.save('foo.pkl')
>>> a = A()
>>> a.some_variable
1

>>> a = A.load('foo.pkl')
>>> a.some_variable
2
```